# ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller route - make everything under home controller appear under the domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Currently everything under homecontroller appears in the URL as

```
example.com/Home/{Action}
```

Is there a way we can keep all other routing the way it is but ONLY special case home controller so everything under home comes under the domain.

like

```
example.com/about
example.com/contact
example.com/error
```

instead of creating new controller classes for each of them.

EDIT:

The other URL's like

```
example.com/user/details/123
example.com/user/edit/123
```

Which are in the userController should work the same as they are now

Comment: routes.MapRoute("Default", "{action}", new {controller = "Home", action = "{action}"});

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best way is:

```
 routes.MapRoute("home", "home", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 routes.MapRoute("about", "about", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
 routes.MapRoute("contact", "contact", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });

 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

and when you want to create a link, use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Home", "home", new{/* route values */}, new {/* html attribues */})
```

OR:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Home", "home")
```

instead of:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new{/* route values */}, new {/* html attribues */})
```

this works for me, and should work for you too.

> UPDATE:

you can create a symbol like `@` (or `-` or anything else), before the `action` part in url, to make the url unique, such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "test",  // route name
    "@{action}", // url and parameters
    new {controller = "MyHome", action = "Home"} // parameter defaults
    );
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
     );
```

in this way, your urls are different from the Default map-route and you can create urls like:

```
site.com/@Home
site.com/@About
site.com/@Contact
```

but the first, in my idea, is better and I always use that.

Comment: This is what i just found out and started doing. And this works for me.. except that actionlink also works correctly for me. (it gives the desired urls)

Comment: But if someone has another clever way so we dont have to repeat these lines of code for EVERY action i add to the home controller that would be great. I will mark this as an answer for now,

Comment: the another way, (for your second comment), is to create a symbol (for example @ or - or anything else), before action-part, that I insert an example of this, in answer's update.

Comment: that is a pretty good solution - i might endup using _ or something.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Attribute Routing of MVC5, I did similar to Javad_Amiry answer, by placing a route for each action in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("about")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I think this is more maintainable than placing every action in the global RouteConfig.cs file. Better still to combine Attribute Routing with convention-based routing, so new actions added to controller will work by default without a Route attribute (eg: /Home/action) but can be improved by adding the Route attribute (eg: /action).

Comment: I agree, tried this and it worked great for me. Catch though: make sure you enable attribute routing in your RouteConfig.cs: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply modify the default route and remove the controller bit from the url and specify that it will always be `Home` in the default values:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Obviously you realize that this limits your application to a single controller which is `HomeController` as now you no longer have any possibility to set it in your url. Stuffing all the actions in a single controller is a bad practice IMHO and violates a couple of principles like RESTful routing and SRP.

Comment: yes, that is why the question .. how to special case ONE controller so i dont have to create a ton of controllers. Thanks.

Comment: @MoXplod, I showed you how in my answer: by modifying the default route in your global.asax and removing the `{controller}` bit from the url.

Comment: Yes, it special cases home BUT breaks the route to all my other controllers. I need all the others to work the way they do right now.

Comment: @MoXplod, I think you totally missed the point of my answer. You cannot have other controllers with such routes :-) How do you expect the routing engine to know which controller you want to be invoked from the following url `/index`? If you want to have other controllers than Home there must be some way to specify them in the url.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC root url’s with generic routing](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/aspnet-mvc-root-urls-with-generic-routing/)

Comment: that solution looks nice and clean, but what about performance, every request is going through reflection to determine the root. But this can be solved by caching the controllers dictionary (which that solution doesnt show)